# Macro Verbosity definition

Tags: c, macros, c99

I have following code snippet

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT( x, fmt, args... ) if (DEBUG_##x || x == 0) {fprintf(fmt, ##args);} else;
```

Where x is the verbosity level.

I want to execute the fprint statement if verbosity x is 0 and when corresponding DEBUG_##x is defined

While compiling an error is throwing as DEBUG_1 is undefined.

My use case is to skip the fprint statement if DEBUG_1 is not defined. Help me crack this logic

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regular `if`. You can use preprocessor to completely remove `printf` if the macro is not defined:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#define TRUTHY_X ,
#define TRUTHY_1X ,

#define RUN_IF(cond, then) RUN_IF_A(CAT(CAT(TRUTHY_, cond), X) then,)
#define RUN_IF_A(...) RUN_IF_B(__VA_ARGS__)
#define RUN_IF_B(cond, then, ...) then

#define DEBUG_PRINT(x, fmt, ...) RUN_IF(CAT(DEBUG_,x),printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__));
```

This assumes that `DEBUG_x` is defined to either an empty string or `1`. This also assumes that `DEBUG_` and some other things are not defined.

I didn't add the special treatment for `x == 0`, but that can be solved with `#define DEBUG_0`.

Comment: This logic is doesn't seem to be even compile without error. If you want the code I tried, I can add it here.

Comment: @runner Both GCC & Clang [do run it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YrYEGo). MSVC errors out, but they're known to have a non-conformant preprocessor. What compiler do you use? Yep, the code would help.